# How is a newline transformed when using transform-from-json

Tags: marklogic

In a rest extension I recieve json. Transform-from-json converts text including '/n'

```
let $jcodes     := '{code:"6626\n1012\n2536\n7890"}'
let $xml        := json:transform-from-json($jcodes)
return $xml
```

Gives in the query console:

```
<json type="object" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
  <code type="string">6626
1012
2536
7890</code>
</json>
```

Question : What character is used to express the newline in de resultbox of the queryconsole?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I don't think it uses newline characters. It uses CSS. If you inspect the HTML, you can see each line is a `<div class="resultItem">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want is `fn:string-to-codepoints` - and `xdmp:describe` can also be useful.

```
string-to-codepoints(
  json:transform-from-json(
    '{code:"6626\n1012\n2536\n7890"}'))

=> (54, 54, 50, 54, 10, 49, 48, 49, 50, 10, 50, 53, 51, 54, 10, 55, 56, 57, 48)
```

So the newline is codepoint 10, which matches what `man ascii` would tell you.

```
 The decimal set:

   0 nul    1 soh    2 stx    3 etx    4 eot    5 enq    6 ack    7 bel
   8 bs     9 ht    10 nl    11 vt    12 np    13 cr    14 so    15 si
  16 dle   17 dc1   18 dc2   19 dc3   20 dc4   21 nak   22 syn   23 etb
```

Comment: In XML the decimal codepoint entity is `&#10;`. That also works in XQuery strings, and XQuery strings can also embed newlines directly - no escaping needed. You also have `fn:codepoints-to-string`. Since this looks like delimited data you might also be interested in `fn:tokenize` - or just use `json:to-array` in the first place.